# Tenured full, Eden empty: can objects be moved to Eden?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand how GC in Java works, and I wonder what would happen in the following situation:

1. Eden: almost full, Surivor1: some minimal utilization, Surivor2: empty, Tenured: almost full.
2. We try to allocate some object, which does not fit in the free space in Eden.
3. GC starts: an attempt to repack Eden+Survivor1 into Survivor2. Most objects deleted, but still not enough space. Spillover tries to go to Tenured.
4. Tenured also does not have enough space to keep all of spillover.

At this point, Eden may already have plenty of space, after deleting dead objects. Can Java GC utilize this free space?

I'm not considering the G1 garbage collector in this question.

Comment: Moving objects from Tenured to Eden would be a logical contradiction. However, at least some of the selectable algorithms can resize the generations (configurable, for most of them, being resizable is the default), which is already a solution for utilizing this space, without the need to move objects.

Answer (score 1):

In the situation you describe, a typical GC algorithm (since you don't ask about a specific one) would cause a major GC to try and reclaim space in the old gen (tenured space) to allow objects to be promoted from the Eden/survivor spaces.

If this could not reclaim enough space to support completion of GC of the young generation you would get an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: So, this would be an argument for making the Young space small?

Comment: It really depends on the profile of your application. If you reduce the size of the young gen. the JVM will have to perform minor GCs more frequently, which will degrade the throughput of your application. Certainly, you could consider making the survivor spaces larger if that was forcing objects to be promoted before the tenuring threshold was reached. Unfortunately, this kind of tuning is more of a black art than a science. Our Zing JVM with C4 GC solves a lot of these problems :-).

Comment: I meant, among probably many arguments for/against the Young space being small, this one would be "for".